# Python Beautifulsoup4 remove <span> tags

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup, html

I am scraping information from a website using this line
`offers =  soup.find_all("span", "rcnt")`
Which gives me this result:
    `[<span class="rcnt">8.668</span>]`
And for some reason when I tried to unwrap it it gave me this
    `[<span class="rcnt"></span>]`
Instead of `8.668`

How do I code this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your description as to what code you are using to get(unwrap) the content. Here is what you do.

`offers` is a list. To get the content within the span elements you do:

```
elements = [tag.text for tag in offers]
```

`elements` will have the contents of all of the span tags in your HTML.

```
>>> html = '<span class="rcnt">8.668</span><span class="rcnt">5.7868</span>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> offers =  soup.find_all("span", "rcnt")
>>> elements = [tag.text for tag in offers]
>>> elements
[u'8.668', u'5.7868']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.string` or `.renderContents()` to get the value.

```
htmls = '<span class="rcnt">8.668</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
offers =  soup.find_all("span", "rcnt")

print offers[0].string           ## this one is better
print offers[0].renderContents()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use .string() to retrieve the value inside any html tag.

```
html = '<span class="rcnt">8.668</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
offers = soup.('span',attrs={"class":"rcnt"})
```

It returns an array of all the span tag.Now you can use .string() function to retrieve the string part within the span tag as:

```
for i in range(0,len(offers)):
 print offers[i]
```